# Run the following method three times with a 1s break on each attempt before throwing exception

Tags: c#

Is it possible to run the following method 3 times (specifically the code within the `try`) before throwing an error message (i.e. fail-retry, fail-retry, fail-retry, throw error message), with a break of 1 seconds between each attempt?

```
    public static int CheckBidDuplicate(int plotId, int operatorId)
    {
        const string query = "SELECT Count(*) FROM bid WHERE plot_id=@plot_id AND operator_id=@operator_id GROUP BY plot_id;";
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, DbConnect.Connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@plot_id"), plotId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@operator_id"), operatorId);
            try
            {
                var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                var dtCounts = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dtCounts);
                var count = dtCounts.Rows.Count;
                return count;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorHandlingComponent.LogError(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Considered using a simple `int counter` and a `Timer`?

Comment: If you don't want to have to keep implementing such logic, maybe look at a package like [Polly](https://github.com/michael-wolfenden/Polly) that lets you express your *policies* cleanly. (Not my project/package, can't guarantee it'll do everything you want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern of execution is reasonably common. I would say in most cases, people implement a helper type to encapsulate the redundant part. For example:

```
static class Retry
{
    public static T Invoke<T>(Func<T> func, int tryCount, TimeSpan tryInterval)
    {
        if (tryCount < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("tryCount");
        }

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                return func();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (--tryCount > 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(tryInterval);
                    continue;
                }

                ErrorHandlingComponent.LogError(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
int result = Retry.Invoke(
    () => CheckBidDuplicate(plotId, operatorId), 3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

In my experience, you may wind up wanting additional features. Customization of logging, customizing of exception handling (e.g. don't bother retrying on certain exceptions known to be terminally fatal), default try-count and try-interval values, that sort of thing.

But the above should be a good starting point.