# Attempting a method multiple times in C#

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates

I have code attempting database transactions.
These can fail due to concurrent access.

I would like to run these in a retry loop. ie. attempt it N times catching a particular exception then throw it.

All code for each transaction is inside of a static function.

```
i.e
protected static ReturnType DoSomething(Connection conn, Arg1Type Arg1, Arg2Type Arg2...)
{
    using (var transaction = conn.GetTransaction)
    {
        ...
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

The best I have been able to come up with is to force all of these functions to be a delegate taking params object[] for all of the arguments. But this throws away all type safety.

Is there a better way of doing it?

Cheers

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for Aspect Oriented Programming AOP

Comment: whats wrong with calling the function x times?

Comment: Because there will be hundreds of these functions within the system. We'd rather not have to wrap each in a for/try/catch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run the following method three times with a 1s break on each attempt before throwing exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322632/run-the-following-method-three-times-with-a-1s-break-on-each-attempt-before-thro)